# How do i check javascript variable on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
var map = new naver.maps.Map('map', mapOptions);

var latlng = map.getCenter();
console.log("latlng variable is ", latlng);
```

I'm using an external API (NAVER map, which is similar to Google map I believe) which runs on Javascript and I'm looking for a way to check a Javascript variable, to debug.

I want to know the value inside `latlng` but I can't see any log on my terminal. 
I googled and read that passing Javascript variable to ruby controller cannot be done directly. However, I'm not trying to pass the variable - I just want to see what's in it.

How can I do this? I can really use some help.

Comment: Did you tried looking into browser console? Normally `console.log` prints the out to the console.

Comment: This javascript runs client-side. Ruby runs server-side. `console.log` will print in the **browser log**, whereas `Rails.log` will print in the **server log**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the browser console. The method for this varies between operating system and browser, but for example [on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) you can press `Ctrl+Shift+J` (Windows / Linux) or `Cmd+Opt+J` (Mac).

In general, you should be able to do something like: Right click --> inspect --> console.

---

Your JavaScript code above is running on the **client side**, i.e. in the browser itself. In order to see any log messages, you need to look at the **browser log**.

This is in contrast to the rails code, which is running on the **server side**. Rails logs appear on the server itself, because that code is not executed by the browser.

I can't see anything wrong with your code, given the information provided. Take a look at the browser log, to see the value of the variable. You can also, for example, set breakpoints in the code - so you wouldn't need to explicitly write `console.log` each time.

Comment: I only checked the server log on my c9 ide but now I can see all the logs on my Chrome browser's console. I just finished Codeacademy JS course so I wasn't aware of codes running on which side. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please try rewrite your '**console.log**' like this:

```
var latlng = map.getCenter();
console.log("latlng variable is "+ latlng);
```

Change '**,**' to '**+**'. 
Then see if you see any **latlng** value on browser log